# Wikidata SPARQL query cast & crew

Tags: sparql, wikidata

My objective is to create a sparql query that retrieves a list of cast and crew and it's wikidata type ("director", "screenwriter", "cast member", ...)

So far I have this:

```
SELECT ?titleLabel ?castLabel ?property ?propertyLabel
WHERE {
    ?title wdt:P345 "tt0848228".
    ?title wdt:P57 ?cast.
    ?property wikibase:propertyType ?propertyType.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

The output I want to achive is a table with rows like:

`"The Avengers", "Joss Whedon", "wd:P57", "director"
...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FtitleLabel%20%3FcastLabel%20%3Fproperty%20%3FpropLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ftitle%20wdt%3AP345%20%22tt0848228%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20take%20all%20claims%20on%20this%20movie%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ftitle%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fcast%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20that%20involve%20a%20human%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcast%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20get%20the%20property%20label%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20see%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FWikidata%3ASPARQL_query_service%2Fqueries%23Adding_labels_for_properties%0A%20%20%20%20hint%3AQuery%20hint%3Aoptimizer%20%22None%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fproperty%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?titleLabel ?castLabel ?property ?propLabel
WHERE {
    ?title wdt:P345 "tt0848228".
    # take all claims on this movie
    ?title ?property ?cast .
    # that involve a human
    ?cast wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .

    # get the property label
    # see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Adding_labels_for_properties
    hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
    ?prop wikibase:directClaim ?property .

    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks!